# How to call JS function outside from AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs

I have JS file with simple function on clear JS:

```
function Alert(){
  alert();
}
```

In another file I have application on Angular JS.
At first connected simple JS file on page and after Angular JS on tags `<head>`

How I can call `Alert()` method  from controller Angular JS?

**Simple JS file:**

```
$(function(){
function leftTimeInit(){
        $.each($('.action-loader'), function(index, val) {
            initLoader($(this), $(this).data('percentage'));
        });
    }
});
```

**Angular JS in controller:**

```
leftTimeInit();
```

I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: leftTimeInit is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do DOM manipulations in your controllers. So you should probably rethink how you want to use that function.

Anyway, `leftTimeInit` is declared in an anonymous function, and only visible there. You can't call it anywhere else. If you want that, you'll have to move it out of `$(function(){})` . But as I've said, not recommended.

As for your Alert() example... In Angular you have access to simple JS global functions via $window (of course, they're global and you could access them anyway, but if you use $window you can mock them in tests).

```
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $window) {
  $window.Alert('something');
});
```